# How to save ssh login welcome banner and disconnect

Tags: bash, ssh, sshpass

I'd like to be able to sign into an ssh terminal and save the banner information, and immediately disconnect. For example i can ssh into my terminal with:

```
sshpass -p[PASSWORD] ssh -p 2201 [USER_NAME]@ipaddress
```

I get the following login welcome banner:

```
Linux 2.6.21 #1 PREEMPT Tue Feb 1 16:12:56 CST 2011
Site ID: xml
Last login: Wed Aug  3 09:25:29 2016 from 156.98.4.11
```

I can pipe the "last login" information with

```
sshpass -p[PASSWORD] ssh -p 2201 [USER_NAME]@ipaddress > lastlogin.txt
```

However, this doesn't save the rest of the banner and I still have to hit ctrl+d to disconnect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's completely unclear where the banner comes from.  It could be generated by the SSH daemon'd `PrintMotd` functionality, or by something in `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, or from startup files of whatever shell you are using.  Without looking at the target system's configuration, it's hard to tell how to extract it.  The "message of the day" is generally only printed when you log in interactively, so redirecting the output will make it disappear.  A better question would be to directly ask how to extract the information you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nemanjas command is great, but be aware that the login banner isn't always located in the same file. On Ubuntu systems it's located in `/etc/issue.net`. The safest way would be to read the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, where the `Banner` attribute is set.

```
grep Banner < /etc/ssh/sshd_config | cut -d' ' -f 2
```

Use this command to extract the file name.

Comment: Thank you, the banner ended up being exactly where you mentioned: /etc/issue.net

Answer (score 2):

The "login welcome banner" is [motd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_(Unix)) (message of the day).

Motd message should be located located in `/etc/motd` and you should be able to copy it to your machine using `scp` command.

The command to do get motd would look something like:

```
sshpass -p [PASSWORD] scp -P [PORT] [USER_NAME]@[IP_OR_HOST]:/etc/motd lastlogin.txt
```